# How can I refer to a module method without referring to the entire namespace?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a module defined as:

```
module MyApp
  module Utility
    def Utility.my_method
```

I want to use that method in several other classes. But I don't want to have to call:

```
MyApp::Utility.my_method
```

I would rather just call:

```
Utility.my_method
```

Is that reasonable? I've tried `include MyApp::Utility` and `include MyApp` to no avail.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7373027

Comment: `include MyApp` works for me in Ruby 1.9.3.  I'm then able to call Utility.my_method.  Not using Rails here though.

Comment: When you include a module its methods become instance methods of the object, so you can just do `include MyApp::Utility` and then `my_method` instead of `Utility.my_method`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just assign any alias you want, e.g.:

```
ShortNameGoesHere = MyApp::Utility
ShortNameGoesHere.my_method
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of mixing in my_method to a class:

```
#myapp.rb
module MyApp
  module Utility
    def my_method
      "called my_method"
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
#test.rb
require './myapp'
class MyClass
  include MyApp::Utility
end

if __FILE__ == $0 then
  m = MyClass.new
  puts m.my_method
end
```

It sounds like you want to maintain the namespace of the module on the mixed-in method.  I have seen attempts to do so (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7575460/149212) but it seems pretty messy.

If you need my_method to be namespaced, you could simply include a module identifier in the method name:

```
module MyApp
  module Utility
    def util_my_method
      "called my_method"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It refuses to work within a class in 1.9.3. Let's say my classname is MyClass, I end up with the error "undefined constant MyClass::Utility. It shouldn't be this hard.

Comment: Are you attempting to mix-in a class method or an instance method?

Comment: I wanted it to be a class method, but I've tried it both ways.

Comment: See the updated answer for an example of mixing in an instance method.  As far as mixing in class methods, maybe look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692961/inheriting-class-methods-from-mixins